# SAPUI5: make embedded video stop on cancel

Tags: javascript, html, video, youtube, sapui5

in an SAPUI5 app I have a dialog which is opened from a button in the footer (see dialog code [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Dialog/preview)).
in this dialog (fragment -> Std3) I have a youtube video embedded like this:

```
 <html:iframe id="video1" height="350" 
    src="//www.youtube.com/embed/mYbn9Q6P0cU?enablejsapi=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true"></html:iframe>
```

What I want is to automatically stop the video when clicking the close button (onDialogCloseButton; snippet is from controller). I have similar code with an embedded video (i.e. not within a dialog and plainly in an xml view)and there it works fine - with: this._pauseVideo1(); 
Please advice what to do here. Thx!

```
    openDialog: function (sType) {
if (!this[sType]) {
  this[sType] = sap.ui.xmlfragment(
    "fragment." + sType + "Dialog",
    this // associate controller with the fragment
  );
  this.getView().addDependent(this[sType]); 
  }

this[sType].bindElement("/ProductCollection/0");
// toggle compact style
jQuery.sap.syncStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact", this.getView(), this[sType]);
this[sType].open();
  },

onStd3DialogPress: function (oEvent) {
this.openDialog('Std3');
 },


  onDialogCloseButton: function (oEvent) {
  var sType = oEvent.getSource().data("dialogType");
  this[sType].close(); 
  this[sType]._pauseVideo1(); 

  },  
 _pauseVideo1: function() {
    var oVideoIFrameWindow = this.byId("video1").$()[0].contentWindow;
      oVideoIFrameWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"pauseVideo","args":""}', '*');
  },
```

Comment: I believe your _pauseVideo1 is a function within your controller.
call this._pauseVideo1() instead of this[sType]._pauseVideo1();
because the later will be referring to your dialog.